# How to explain additional words in the QASV formula for questions?

Tags: questions

I am a new ESL teacher, and will be teaching students about question forms.
I have looked at the QASV (Question, Auxiliary, Subject, Verb) formula but am not sure how to explain all examples my textbook provides.

For example:

- Where does Jamie live? - this fits perfectly to the formula
- What are you doing tomorrow afternoon? - tomorrow afternoon is additional and comes at the end.
- Which instrument does Jamie play? - Why is "instrument" placed after the question word here?

I'm not sure how to explain its place in the sentence. I think some students could say: "Which does Jamie play instrument?" I don't know how to explain why that is wrong.

Comment: I don’t really see why this should present a problem—it’s just a matter of defining what “Q” means. It is a noun phrase which is headed by an interrogative, but which may also contain any number of other elements that can normally appear in a NP, including nouns, adjectives, prepositional phrases, embedded (relative) clauses, etc. They all become part of the “Q”.

Comment: **Qu** = Question word or phrase e.g. "When", "What time/music/film…", "Which green car…", "How long", "How many theatre tickets…"  etc. **A** = auxiliary verb **S** = subject or noun phrase e.g. "she" or "her mother's best friend" **I** = infinitive (QUASI) verb or **V** = any verb form. (QASV) I prefer the former, it's catchier and easier to remember.

Comment: Use this acronym for beginners and at an elementary/pre-intermediate level, I wouldn't remind students of this "trick" at higher levels. It's not foolproof

Comment: Note the difference in word class. 'What does Jamie like?' uses 'what' as an interrogative pronoun, whereas 'What jam does Jamie like?' / 'Whose pen did Jamie borrow?' / 'Which instrument does Jamie play?' show the interrogative determiner usage. See, for instance, [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/whose).